# Angular $http data is not available in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

var eateryControllers=angular.module('eateryApp');

```
eateryControllers.controller('ReservationController',['$scope','$http','$location',function($scope,$http,$location){
    var resvnCtrl=this;
    resvnCtrl.user={};
    resvnCtrl.confirmation={};

    resvnCtrl.submitForm=function(isValid){
        if(isValid==true){
            $http({
                  method: 'POST',
                  url: '/Eatery/save',
                  contentType:'application/json',
                  dataType:'json',
                  data:resvnCtrl.user
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    resvnCtrl.confirmation=response.data;
                    $location.path("/reservation/confirmation");
                    console.log(resvnCtrl.confirmation);
              }, function errorCallback(response) {

             });
        }
        else{
            //show errors
        }

    }
}]);
```

**view**

```
<div class="container" data-ng-controller="ReservationController as resvnCtrl">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td> <td>{{resvnCtrl.confirmation.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I am pulling some data with $http and storing that in controller object. But i could not print in that view. in the above example console statement printed data. but the same data in not available in view.

Anything wrong with my code

Comment: i am using controller as approach. code updated

Comment: How do you render it in the HTML?

Comment: code updated with view

Comment: Why do you change the path? I think the problem is that, remove $location.path and you should see the data

Comment: I have a form. after form submission, i am posting the data. i want to show the response back to user. so i am redirecting user to a confirmation page and the displaying response on that page

Comment: No that's wrong, you can simply change the DOM in the current page to display the response you can use ng-if ng-show ng-hide etc...

Comment: what if i need a new template to display that repsonse. do i need to pull the data again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you are changing the location path it is trying to load another controller (may be same ReservationController) then it is initializing your controller again with the following line.

```
resvnCtrl.confirmation={};
```

Note: $location.path("/reservation/confirmation"); //is not stoping execution of next line. So you are getting console print.

Answer (score 1):

Ok You need to understand in depth sometimes  what is the life time of `$scope` and global var also how long it hold's the data ..., coming to the point

You wanna to show the confirmation page based on the resultant data.My suggestion is you could store resultant data in service .

First could you please create angular `service` also it has a var to hold the data then `inject` it in your controller and use it like

```
resvnCtrl.submitForm=function(isValid){
    if(isValid==true){
        $http({
              method: 'POST',
              url: '/Eatery/save',
              contentType:'application/json',
              dataType:'json',
              data:resvnCtrl.user
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                service.confirmData = angular.copy(response.data);
                $location.path("/reservation/confirmation");
                console.log(resvnCtrl.confirmation);
          }, function errorCallback(response) {

         });
    }
    else{
        //show errors
    }
```